# Regex - extract {search string} + first 10 next characters

Tags: regex

I'd like to search for {search string} and show "search string" + the next 10 characters. How do i do this with Regex?

Comment: I tried:
Search value^.{0,3}
"Search value"^.{0,3}
%Search value%^.{0,3}

Comment: Edit you question instead of using comment. It'll be more readable. Question, Are the curly brackets part of the search sting? You should also add the language you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
searchstring.{0,10}
```

This will match for instance:

- hellosearchstring123 > searchstring123
- searchstringxxxxxxxxxxyyyyy > searchstringxxxxxxxxxx